# How can I mount /dev from C?

Tags: mount, devices, init, system-calls

How can I mount `/dev` from C? I'm writing a simple init, and I know this sounds stupid but I would like to have `/dev` mounted to another folder.
The manpages for `mount()` don't show `dev` as a supported option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to populate /dev directory when building my own initrd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52713/how-to-populate-dev-directory-when-building-my-own-initrd)

Comment: @sebasth Almost, but I need to be able to do it from C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [manpage for `mount(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) only gives examples and mentions `/proc/filesystems` for an exhaustie list. This latter file lists `devtmpfs` which is what you are looking for.

The resulting C program would then be something like:

```
if (mount("-", "/.../dev", "devtmpfs", 0, NULL) != 0) perror("mount");
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!

Comment: You're welcome! This is a minimal example and you may want to customize it by adding flags (mount options) like `MS_NOATIME`, `MS_NOEXEC`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have `/dev` mounted elsewhere by using the mount command.

If you want to use the `mount` system call directly, the man page says

> Values for the filesystemtype argument supported by the kernel are listed in `/proc/filesystems`.

If you are not sure which filesystem type you want on `/dev` look at your `/etc/fstab` or `/proc/mounts`, or do a `strace` on the mount command to find out how it uses the system call.